# Getting my text to go over the background image

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div style="background-image: url('images/middle.png'); height: 390px; width: 900px; margin-top:190px; color:#000000;">
</div>
```

which produces this:
[image]

But when i put text in the div, no matter how much margins or anything i put on it does this:
[image]

But i want the text be on the white image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `margin` is of no use for this use `padding`. I tried with the following and it worked!

```
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.stack.imgur.com/uisvJ.png&quot;); height: 390px; width: 900px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); margin-top: 0px; padding-left: 35px; padding-top: 25px;">
my text appears here and on top of the image
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need `padding` rather than `margin`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="background-image: url('images/middle.png'); height: 390px; width: 900px; margin-top:190px; color:#000000; >
   <div style="text-align:center;padding-top:XXXXXXpx">Hello there</div>
</div>
```

set padding-top:XXXXXXpx to what ever you need;

second solution is to set in inner div style to margin: **top** auto;  and width: 100px (if it is enough for text, can be less or more) Change **top** in pixels how much you need your text be far from outer div

Also, next time, please add more in description, like where that text should appear :)